# How can I apply event handlers to new elements without refreshing the tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JQuery function:

```
$('.btn-cart-toggle').on({
    click: function () {
        if (!CheckZero()) {
            if ($('.cart-bubble').hasClass('active')) {
                $('.cart-bubble').removeClass("active");
                $('.cart-bubble').addClass("hidden");
            }
            else {
                $('.cart-bubble').addClass("active");
                $('.cart-bubble').removeClass("hidden");
            }
        }
    }, mouseenter: function () {
        if ($('.cart-bubble').hasClass('active') != true && !CheckZero()) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            $('#notificacion-perfil').hide();
            if ($('.cart-bubble ul.items li').size() > 0) {
                if ($('.cart-bubble').hasClass('hidden')) {
                    $('.cart-bubble').removeClass("hidden");
                }
            }
        }
    }, mouseleave: function () {
        if ($('.cart-bubble').hasClass('active') != true) {
            if ($('.cart-bubble').hasClass('hidden') != true) {
                timer = setTimeout(function () {
                    $('.cart-bubble').addClass("hidden");
                }, 800);
            }
        }
    }, dblclick: function () {
        if (!CheckZero()) {
            $('.cart-bubble').removeClass("active");
            $('.cart-bubble').addClass("hidden");
        }
    }
});
```

The CheckZero() function checks if there are li elements inside something and returns true or false.

Everything works fine, but at the moment I add a li element I have to refresh the page to be able of toggling the .cart-bubble classes

Comment: You're not using `on()` correctly. See any of the mountain of answers on SO referring to "event delegation", or check the docs. http://api.jquery.com/on

Comment: use `bind` instead of `on`.

Comment: when you create `li` elements after the above code is running, the events will not apply to the new created list items. you has to bind them seperately when adding new elements.

Comment: What isn't working on your edit? what are you trying to achieve, and what is failing? Have you debugged it?

Comment: What i'm trying is that clicking outside the .cart-bubble makes it 'close'. it was working before the changes, now everything is working fine but this

Comment: It would be a good idea if you left the question as it originally was, or if you explained what was going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `event delegate`

```
$('document').on('click','.btn-cart-toggle',function () {
  //your code
});
```

Comment: However, this makes you change the syntax you were using. You can see my answer to keep using your own syntax, but with the necessary change to make it work as delegated event.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a syntax like the one you're using but have to modify it a little bit.

Now you have this:

```
$('selector').on(eventObject)
```

What this does is to subscribe the events to the selected objects already exisintg in the page.

If you need to subscribe to objects which will existe in the future you have to do it this way:

```
$('parent selector').on(eventObject,'filter');
```

If you do it this way you have to specify:

- the "parent selector" must select a DOM element which contains all the elements whose events you want to handle
- the "filter" must select only the DOM elements whose events you want to handle

No doubt, this will work for you:

```
$('document').on(eventObject,'.btn-cart-toggle');
```

But most probably you can choose an element smaller than the document itself.

How does it work? The events bubble up through the DOM element tree. When the event reaches the 'parent object' it checks if the element which started the event fulfills the filter. If so, the event is handled. If not, nothing is done.

Comment: Great explanation, thanks!

However I'm having trouble now, using a function I'll add it to the question